# Letter Tile Possibilities - Java solution

Tags: java, permutation

Trying to solve the "Letter Tile Possibilities" problem

For a given input, require to calculate the number of possible sequences. Not sure what went wrong with my program.

**The program works fine for the following input**

Input: "AAB"

Output: 8

Explanation: The possible sequences are "A", "B", "AA", "AB", "BA", "AAB", "ABA", "BAA".

**Program fails when I change the input to this**

Input: "AAABBC"

Expected Output: 188 (Correct Answer).

But the program is returning - 164

Code

```
    int[] factorial = new int[]{1,1,2,6,24,120,720};
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public int numTilePossibilities(String tiles) {
        char[] array = tiles.toCharArray();
        int total_sequences = 0;
        int total = array.length;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            addToMap(array[i]);
        }
        for(int digit = 1; digit<=total; digit++)
        {
            int numerator = factorial[total];
            int denominator = (factorial[total-digit] * getRepetitions());    

            total_sequences += Math.round((float)((float)numerator/(float)denominator));
            System.out.println("Digit "+digit+" Sequences "+Math.round((float)((float)numerator/(float)denominator))+" N "+ numerator+" D"+denominator+" Rep"+ getRepetitions() );
        }
        return total_sequences;
    }   

    private Integer getRepetitions()
    {
        int denominator = 1;
            for(String key : map.keySet())
            {
                    if(map.get(key)==1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    denominator=  ((denominator)*factorial[map.get(key)]);
            }
        return denominator;
    }

    private void addToMap(char tile)
    {
        Integer counter = map.get(tile+"");
        if(counter == null)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        map.put(tile+"",counter);
    }


}
```